# Blank browser page on Jupyter notebook - Custom CSS?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Whenever i try to spawn a notebook my terminal looks like the following: 
[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9h2N3.png)

Then i get a blank browser page:
[ChromeConsole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uOlG.png)

Any ideas as to why its looking for a custom css?
Why are these suddenly throwing errors of "MIME" type?

Python version       3.6.8
jupyter              1.0.0
jupyter-client       5.2.4
jupyter-console      6.0.0
jupyter-core         4.4.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55252159/jupyter-notebook-opens-an-empty-browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same identical problem with Opera and Brave (both chromium-based) and Microsoft Edge (Python version 3.6.8 and Jupyter version 1.0.0). There is an open issue on github here https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4467 describing the same issue we are having.

The solution that worked for me was rolling back to notebook version 5.7.5 as detailed here: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4467#issuecomment-471619994 and correcting the page.html file (obviously, the one corresponding to the conda env or pipenv that you are using) as detailed here: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4467#issuecomment-471867371.

I'm sorry if this is a bit hacky. I am not really sure what the underlying issue is, but at least it works.

Comment: I ended up switching to Windows 10 from Windows 8 last night and that seemed to fix it! :) haha.
Marking it as answered. Thank you.