# Jupyter Notebook opens an empty browser

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Before I've installed python 3.6 and update all (conda update --all) my Jupyter Notebook just stopped to works. When I launch it, just an empty browser page appears. I tried all solutions that I found, but they don't work. I have deleted %USERBLABLA%, clear cache and cookies, uninstall and install it again and it still doesn't work. Browser console prints this errors:

```
Refused to execute script from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at VM17 tree:24
```

Comment: Thiscan  often be fixed by a deep reload in the browser (Ctrl+F5 on most systems).

Comment: Nope, I've already tried

Comment: Have you tried a different browser? Or a reboot :)

Comment: Yes. Even uninatall and install again, but when I update all, its just stop working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the version of Notebook on Anaconda Navigator. 
If it's 5.7.6 then you should downgrade the notebook's version to 5.7.4 by using the Anaconda Navigator.

Comment: Thanks you man, you really helped! I just did everything that I found and only your tip worked. Thank you!

Comment: @demo Jupyter lab won't work as well with 5.7.6. 5.7.4 is ok with JupyterLab 0.35.2 or 0.35.3